# android: parse html from page

Tags: android

i would like to parse out some text from a page.

Is there an easy way to save the product info in to a string for example? Example url: http://upcdata.info/upc/7310870008741

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jsoup is excellent at parsing simple HTML from Android applications:

http://jsoup.org/

To get the page, just do this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://upcdata.info/upc/7310870008741");
Document document = Jsoup.parse(url, 5000);
```

Then you can parse out whatever you need from the `Document`. Check out this link for a brief description of how to extract parts of the page:

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read from a URL into a String:

```
StringBuffer myString = new StringBuffer();
try {
    String thisLine;
    URL u = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    DataInputStream theHTML = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());
    while ((thisLine = theHTML.readLine()) != null) {
        myString.append(thisLine);
    } 
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {

} catch (IOException e) {

}

// call toString() on myString to get the contents of the file your URL is
// pointing to.
```

This will give you a plain old string, HTML markup and all.

Answer (score 1):

```
String tmpHtml = "<html>a whole bunch of html stuff</html>"; 
String htmlTextStr = Html.fromHtml(tmpHtml).toString();
```